# KeyListener only sometimes works

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

I am writing a game and I have just tried to add the KeyListener. I have experience with java including KeyListeners but I for some reason cannot figure out why this code only works some of the time.

Here is my listener function:

```
public void Listener() { 
    System.out.println("[INFO] Listener() Ran.");

    KeyListener kl = new KeyListener() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyChar()=='a'){
                System.out.println("[DEBUG] A Pressed.");
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    };
    panel.addKeyListener(kl);
    System.out.println("[DEBUG] panel added KeyListener.");
}
```

This code works probably only 1 out of 10 times that I run it. Maybe even less. Any ideas on why this is?

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work? And what else have you added to the panel? Might those controls be accepting keys instead?

Answer (score 1):

The getKeyChar should be called in the keyTyped. The `getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A` in the other both methods.